# cannot find package on travis-ci -golang

Tags: build, go, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to run a go script as part of the build process. The script imports a 'custom' package.  However I get this import error.
 The repository name is `bis`. The script which I run is `configbis.go`. The package imported `configbis.go` is `mymodule`

The project structure is as following:

```
bisrepo -------
 |            |
mymodule    configbis.go
```

go run `configbis.go`

```
configbis.go:16:2: cannot find package "bisrepo/mymodule" in any of:

/home/travis/.gvm/gos/go1.1.2/src/pkg/bisrepo/mymodule (from $GOROOT)

/home/travis/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.1.2/global/src/bisrepo/mymodule (from $GOPATH)
```

I've tried to import mymodule in configbis.go as  following:

```
import "mymodule"
import "bisrepo/mymodule"
import "github.com/user/bisrepo/mymodule"
```

None of them works. I run out of ideas/options ... 
I read the the [travis-ci](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/) documentation and I found it useless.

Comment: What is `$GOPATH` set to when you try to run the script?

Comment: from the error I can only assume it is /home/travis/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.1.2/global/src/  . The doc doesn't say much ( http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/ )

Comment: Execute `echo $GOPATH` in a terminal. What does it say? That would help us solve your issue.

Comment: It says /home/travis/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.1.2/global. Same as in the error

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add something like that in your `.travis.yml`:

```
install:
    - go get github.com/user/bisrepo/mymodule
```

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat I guess you should try Travis CI for private repos then

Answer (score 0):

in order to use private repos you must provide a github api auth token (similarly so when deploying go projects which reference private repos on Heroku). You can try adding something like this in your `.travis.yml`

```
before_install:
- echo "machine github.com login $GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN" > ~/.netrc
```

Comment: what about local packages (e.g. "bisrepo/mymodule" ) ?